# Does lms filter does not depend on input or desired signal?

Tags: matlab, filtering

This question referes to the link related to the lms filter.
http://au.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/adaptfilt.lms.html

The filter is called by ha = adaptfilt.lms(32,mu);My question how the adaptfilt.lms is calculating the output 'h' when it was not given the desired or the signal? Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Your title needs to be fixed. But I was wondering what it should be instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant code from the example:

```
x  = randn(1,500);     % Input to the filter
b  = fir1(31,0.5);     % FIR system to be identified
n  = 0.1*randn(1,500); % Observation noise signal
d  = filter(b,1,x)+n;  % Desired signal
mu = 0.008;            % LMS step size.
ha = adaptfilt.lms(32,mu);
[y,e] = filter(ha,x,d);
```

Look at the lines:

```
ha = adaptfilt.lms(32,mu);
[y,e] = filter(ha,x,d);
```

The lms filter is being fed with, the input and the desired output and the system order.

Comment: I assumed adaptfilt.lms is the one which is calculating the weights 'h' but it does not take any other input but mu and 32?

Comment: Lms is an adaptative filter. The inputs and outputs to the unknown system are the "other inputs", on the filter step.

Comment: I am really sorry, but how it is adopting without knowing the input output? Or what exactly adaptfilt.lms  is doing?

Comment: Please read, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter . The objective of an lms filter is not to filter a signal, but make predictions on an unknown system. say you have a system that  changes, because of weather, temperature or something else, you can control or know the  system input, and you can read the system output, but you need to predict that output before it's available to make some decision.

Comment: With LMS you approximate the current unknown system to a model of order N, then use that model to make predictions of the output. Afterwards when the unknown system output values are available, you compare them to your prediction and correct your model to get better estimation on the next input.

Comment: If I understand your question, `ha` doesn't contain coefficients, but an adaptive filter object when it's created, it's "coefficients" are estimated as it filters the input and compares it to the output..

Comment: adaptfilt.lms command creates the adaptive filter object with the parameters for filter length and step-size. The filter command used on this object takes signal and desired signal to adapt.